# Is ('a -> unit) the only function of that type?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I've got a function:

```
fn a => ();
```

And I was wondering, is this the only function that can produce the same type output of: `'a -> unit`?

If so, are there any other functions that only have one type output?

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking – the input of this function is an `'a` and the output is a `unit`, there are many functions whose result is `unit`, and all functions only have one type of output.

Comment: The function is polymorphic, I was wondering if there was any other function that produces this exact output. If you're saying all functions only have one type of output, then if a function had type: 'a -> 'b -> ('a * 'b), that would be the only function that exists of that type @molbdnilo?

Comment: If you're talking about *pure* functions, there is only one function of type `'a -> unit`.

Comment: I assume I am talking about pure functions haha, and does that go for any other polymorphic function? And why is it the only function of that type?

Comment: Oh, you probably mean the output *as seen in the interpreter*, i.e. the function's type. (Not the output of the function.)

Comment: I can't give you a formal proof, but consider how many ways you can map an arbitrary set to the single element `()`.  It can't depend on the input, so you can't do anything more than return `'()`.

Comment: Yeah like if you type in the function it will return `val it = fn : 'a -> unit;`

What about if i had a function `'a -> 'b -> ('a * 'b)`? Would it be the same thing?

Comment: @madcrazydrumma You shouldn't need to *assume* that you are talking about pure functions, you should presumably know what you are asking about -- and know the point of molbdnilo asking about purity.  In SML `unit` is kind of a kludge for incorporating impure functions (functions which work via side effects) into the type system. There are infinitely many nonequivalent nonpure polymorphic functions with return type `unit` which can be defined in SML. `unit` is uninteresting as a return type for pure functions.

Comment: "Only" requires some concept of equality. How are you defining equality of functions?

Comment: I can think of many pure functions that have that type, e.g. `fn a => hd [()]` or `fn a => #1 ((), 42)`. Whether you consider these the same function is another matter

Comment: @newact Equality of functions is well-defined in mathematics. Two functions are equal if they have the same domain and, for all values in the domain, they have the same output. Since it is generally undecidable if two computable functions are in fact equal, it isn't the most useful concept in computer science. Using this definition of function equality then you could prove that if a set, B, has exactly 1 element then for any set A, the set {f : f maps A to B} has exactly 1 element.